# Select rows with the second largest date in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I am trying to select the rows with second latest date in SQL Server 2008.  I want to pull the second latest date for each ID.

```
+----+-----------+
|ID  |Date       |
+----+-----------+
|01  |2017-01-01 |
|01  |2016-04-25 |
|01  |2015-01-25 |
|02  |2017-02-01 |
|02  |2016-03-15 |
|02  |2015-09-24 |
|03  |2017-02-12 |
|03  |2016-03-05 |
|03  |2015-01-02 |
+----+-----------+
```

So I want to end up with:

```
+---+-----------+
|01 |2016-04-25 |
|02 |2016-03-15 |
|03 |2016-03-05 |
+---+-----------+
```

I have figured out how to pull the maxdate but not the second latest date. Any help is greatly appreciated.  This forum is so helpful for a newbie like me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
SELECT id, date 
FROM
(
    SELECT id, date, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM table_name
) t
WHERE rn = 2;
```

If you have multiple rows with second latest date, you should consider changing `ROW_NUMBER()` to `RANK()`

Comment: Thanks so much!! I was trying to figure this out for 2 hours. You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT MAX(date) From Employee WHERE date< ( SELECT Max(date) FROM table);

or

SELECT MAX(date) FROM Employee WHERE date NOT IN ( SELECT Max(date) FROM table);

Read more: http://www.java67.com/2015/01/second-highest-salary-in-mysql-and-sql-server.html#ixzz4ZUWYpZ1p

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
     Create table SampleTable(ID INT ,Dates Date)

     insert into SampleTable values(01 ,'2017-01-01')
     insert into SampleTable values(01 ,'2016-04-25')
     insert into SampleTable values (01 ,'2015-01-25')
     insert into SampleTable values(02 ,'2017-02-01') 
     insert into SampleTable values(02 ,'2016-03-15')
     insert into SampleTable values (02 ,'2015-09-24')
     insert into SampleTable values (03 ,'2017-02-12') 
     insert into SampleTable values (03 ,'2016-03-05' )
     insert into SampleTable values (03 ,'2015-01-02')


select id, dates from (select id,dates,row_number() over (partition by id order by id desc )rowno from SampleTable)x where x.rowno=2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but the first one worked, so I am good to go!